# Hyperref linking to wrong item in TOC(Lyx)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, lyx

I added the `hyperef` package and a TOC to my document using Lyx's built-in options.
It seemed to work almost perfect except one problem: the first item in the TOC is linked to the page of the second item, the second item is linked to the page of the third item, etc..(the last item is not linked at all).

I have a feeling that the solution is quite simple, but all of my efforts to solve it were to no avail.

edit: this is a part from the source code, I'm not sure which part is relevant.

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\section{eno}\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{eno}
\L{$TEXTEXTEXTEXTXET$}
\newpage
\section{owt}\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{owt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Sounds like missing `\phantomsection` statements, but as long as we do not see the code and know, what is linked wrongly, it is just an assumption

Comment: Hey, I added an image of the preamble. I did read about \phantomsection, but didn't understand where should I put the command at the Lyx document.

Comment: @TalWanish: Do not post a screenshot of the code, but copy the code into the editor window of your post.

Comment: I posted a representing example of the problem, this time I tried to use \phantomsection. Still, section one linking to section two, and section two is not clickable at all.

Comment: @TalWanish: Your code does not run, since that `\AtBeginDocument{...}` command with the theorem counter. As well, not anybody has Hebrew and corresponding fonts installed (at least in my case, it fails.) And why do you use `\addcontentsline` for subsections which do not exist? If I run your code after small changes, I got the expected behaviour

Comment: When I converted the document to English with the changes you mentioned, it worked. When I try to do exactly the same (just by changing the language settings) in Hebrew the problem reoccurs.

Comment: @TalWanish: I am afraid, but I cannot provide help on this, since I have no idea, what `Hebrew` language settings might change, apart from right to left writting.